# Целесообразность хранения данных

Tags: база-данных, связывание-данных

Есть две таблицы:

1. Чек - данные о продаже.
2. Транзакция - данные о списании/начисления по продаже.

Чек будет всегда, транзакция может быть или нет.

Допустим, произошла продажа (создании Чека) и были действия с бонусами.

Варианты хранения данных о такой продаже:

1. Делать дополнительную таблицу. Где будет храниться данные о такой продаже, то есть id Чека и id Транзакции.
2. Записывать в таблице Транзакции id Чека.

Как лучше хранить подобную "связность" сущностей? И почему?

Comment: Зависит исключительно от того может ли по одной транзакции пройти 2 чека или к одному чеку пройти две транзации. Если множественность возможна - без вариантов, отдельная таблица. Если такая ситуация исключена 1 чек - 0 или 1 транзакция - то id чека в транзакцию или в чек id транзакции

Comment: @Mike, по одному чеку может быть несколько транзакций.а если быть точнее 2(не больше. но может быть и 0) - начисление и списание,у начисления и списания есть отличительная черта - id типа транзакции. Предполагается довольна большая база, и целесообразно ли будет джойнить три таблицы, а не две.

Comment: главное тогда что бы транзакции с несколькими чеками не оказалось. А так, конечно в саму транзакцию кладите, смысла в отдельной таблице в такой ситуации нет.

Comment: заодно если уникальный индекс id-чека - вид транзакции, в таблице транзакций, сделаете - обеспечите невозможность двух одинаковых операций по чеку. Хотя тут от СУБД зависит, если транзакции без чегов могут быть - то такой индекс им помешает, если СУБД включает NULL значения в индекс